# Passing array to other components after calling Api in react using context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to pass an array of data as props (using context) to another component Carousello.js

But I’m unable to retrieve data on my Home.js component.

This is My HomeContext.js Component:

I use context to calling the API and then passing data to Home.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

export const HomeContext = createContext();

export const HomeProvider = (props) => {
    let array = []
    axios.get(`/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/15`)
        .then(function (res) {
            let slider = res.data.acf.slider
            array.push(slider)
        })
    console.log(typeof (array))
    let ar = array.flat()
    console.log(ar)
    return (
        <HomeContext.Provider value={[array]}>
            {props.children}
        </HomeContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

This is my Carosello.js component where i try to retrive data and render it with jsx:

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react'
import sfondo from './sfondo-gray.jpg'
import { HomeProvider, HomeContext } from './HomeContext';

const Carosello = () => {
    const [acf] = useContext(HomeContext)
    console.log(acf)
    return (
        <div id="myCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
           <h1> {acf.title} </h1>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Carosello
```

Comment: react rerender only on update of state, props, not just changing value of a variable, so your changes are not rendered  because `let array = []` is just a local variable, using state wil do the job

Answer (score 1):

You probably also need to wrap your axios call in a function to use inside `useEffect`. For more detailed info on that, check these: [A complete guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) and [fetchind data with useEffect](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data). Basically, using the `[]` (empty list of dependencies) to trigger one-time action doesn't always work as you would expect from class components' `componentDidMount`.

```
export const HomeProvider = (props) => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=> {
    function fetchData() {
      axios.get(`/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/15`)
      .then(function (res) {
        let slider = res.data.acf.slider
        setArray([...slider.flat()])
        })
      }

      fetchData();
  }, [])

  return (
      <HomeContext.Provider value={[array]}>
          <>{props.children}</>
      </HomeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

export const HomeContext = createContext();

export const HomeProvider = ({children}) => {
    // array type
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    axios.get(`/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/15`)
        .then(function (res) {
            let slider = res.data.acf.slider
            setItems([...slider.flat()])
        })

    return (
        <HomeContext.Provider value={{
            array:items
        }}>
            {children}
        </HomeContext.Provider>
    )
} 

const Carosello = () => {

    // object destructuring
    const {array} = useContext(HomeContext)

    return (
        <div id="myCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
            {/* if is array, try to map or [key] */}
           <h1> {array[0].title} </h1>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Carosello
`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function HomeProvider(){
   const [array, setArray] = React.useState([]);
   React.useEffect(()=> {
     axios.get(`/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/15`)
        .then(function (res) {
            let slider = res.data.acf.slider
            setArray((arr)=> [...arr, slider])
        })
   }, [])
   return (
        <HomeContext.Provider value={[array]}>
            {props.children}
        </HomeContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Object are not valid as a react child Error

Comment: Yes, you should write `<>{props.children}</>`
Doc: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html